# Non-random residual plots from weighted nonlinear least squares regression

Tags: nonlinear-regression, heteroscedasticity, residuals

[Are the residuals from a nonlinear regression model supposed to be randomly distributed too (as in linear regression)] if the data is heteroscedastic and the objective function is weighted by the inverse of the variance for each data point?

This question was asked and answered in part here: [Residual plot for nonlinear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105670/residual-plot-for-nonlinear-regression)

The answer mentions that the model may induce some structure in the residuals, "but taking a Taylor approximation to first order, the nonlinear model is approximated by a linear model, so even that structure will tend to be similar to that of a linear model near the optimum."

Can application of weighted nonlinear least squares to heteroscedastic data induce significant structure in the residuals?

Thank you.